# Can vertical scrolling with ul and li be done via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, vertical-scrolling

Example : http://www.net-a-porter.com/product/163606

So far my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
li {float:left;height:50px}
</style>
<div style="height:100px">
    <a href="#" class="top">up</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
        <li>Product 4</li>
        <li>Product 5</li>
        <li>Product 6</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="down">down</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shai. Do you know why this is not working. I am finding out if there is more than three LI than show arrows. Otherwise do not show arrows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var ulx;
var totalli;
ulx     = document.getElementById("mycarousel");
totali  = ulx.children.length;
if (totali > 3){
        $(".jcarousel-next").hide();
        $(".jcarousel-prev").hide();
    }else{
        // buttons appear
    }
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 2
    });
});
```

UPDATED - Solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var ulx     =   document.getElementById("mycarousel");
var totalli =   ulx.children.length;
if (totalli > 3) { 
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({vertical:true,scroll:2});
} else {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({vertical:true,scroll:2});
    $(".jcarousel-next").hide();$(".jcarousel-prev").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: In your solution, in the }else{ i don't see a reason for the jCarousel() function , since you're hiding the arrow. Other than that it looks fine :)

Comment: Basically if I don't put that in... the Carosel does not appear  (the UL gets automatic styles assigned to it using that command - so my CSS is dependant on it) my script above just hides the arrows but still shows the carosel in place as CSS and code is dependant on it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You could post the inner UL inside a div with overflow:hidden, and move the inside UL's position up and down, and by that creating a sort of a scroll effect.

Comment: Yep, and that's exactly what the site he linked to is doing.

Comment: I didn't look at the link, but yeah- it seems the same more or less :)

Comment: Can you show me an example? Like with the jQuery functions on the buttons??

I know you need to use $('.up').click(function(e){

Comment: I think for this specific purpose using jQuery Carousell would be fastest. http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples

Comment: Thank you so much! Seriously. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. Thank you!